# Getting segmentation fault *sometimes* from an attempt at a selection sort implementation

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, segmentation-fault

I've attempted to debug this on my own, but I can't figure it out! 
I'm getting segmentation faults sometimes when running my code, when there's not a seg fault it runs just fine and works. Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks! Also, please keep in mind that I'm new to C++.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> selection_sort(vector<int> numbers) {
    int lowest_number_index;
    int lowest_number;
    int starting_size = numbers.size();
    vector<int> sorted_numbers;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i) {

        // Find the lowest number
        if (numbers[i] <= lowest_number) {
            lowest_number_index = i;
            lowest_number = numbers[lowest_number_index];
        }

        // Found it! Now let's add it to the other array
        // and remove it from this one.
        if (i == numbers.size() - 1 && numbers.size() != 1) {
            sorted_numbers.push_back(lowest_number);
            numbers.erase(numbers.begin() + lowest_number_index);

            // If we're not done sorting
            if (sorted_numbers.size() != starting_size) {
                lowest_number_index = 0;
                lowest_number = numbers[lowest_number_index];
                // Continue sorting
                i = -1;
                continue;
            }
        } else if (numbers.size() == 1) {
            sorted_numbers.push_back(numbers[i]);
        }
    }

    return sorted_numbers;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> to_sort { 15, 2, 41, 5, 4, 5, 4, 6 };
    to_sort = selection_sort(to_sort);

    cout << "Sorted: ";
    for (auto it = to_sort.begin(); it != to_sort.end(); ++it) {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Problem 1: That's not a selection sort. Selection sort is an in-place sort, and you're removing items from the input list and adding them to an output list. A proper selection sort operates on the input list, transforming it into the sorted list. If this is for an assignment, don't spend too much effort debugging this code because the answer is wrong. Odds are pretty good that it is wrong  because you are overrunning the end of the input list because it changed size while you were using it.

Comment: Okay, wasn't aware that a selection sort had to be in-place. This isn't an assignment, and the input list's size being changed is properly handled so that is not causing an error. Vlad already answered the question correctly.

Comment: OK. my guess on the cause was wrong. @VladfromMoscow has the bug fix and it still holds once you get the vector handling sorted out with a swap.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing out that the selection sort is in-place, I'm working on fixing it now.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't want to edit the main post, but is this a correct implementation of a selection sort? http://pastebin.com/ui3Q3WfZ

Comment: Not quite. You need two loops, an outer and an inner. Outer marches from index 0 to the second last element (because the last element will be sorted by the time you get there) and the inner loop marches from the index of the outer loop to the end of the array looking for the lowest value. [Wiki's implementation looks pretty readable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Implementation), use it as a basis using your vector instead of a vanilla array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function has undefined behaviour because there is used uninitialized variable `lowest_number`

```
int lowest_number;
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//...
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i) {

    // Find the lowest number
    if (numbers[i] <= lowest_number) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Take into account that variable `lowest_number_index` is also uninitialized.

```
int lowest_number_index;
```

Comment: @ChemicalStudios It seems that the function in any case is wrong.

Comment: So I've been told by @user4581301 I will work on the solution to make it in-place.